# How to keep first item of the chekboxlist selected on page load?

Tags: asp.net

I want to know that suppose I have a checkboxlist control with say 5 items, and I want that on page load the very first item i.e I want the item all of the checkboxlist should remain selected by default. How can I accomplish this task.Please guide me.
My checkboxlist with items-

```
{<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chktopics" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
        RepeatLayout="Flow" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="chktopics_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>}
```

Comment: in your ListItem, there is a property called "Selected" - set it to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Selected="true"

```
<asp:ListItem Selected="true">All</asp:ListItem>
```

Your code would be

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chktopics" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
    RepeatLayout="Flow" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="chktopics_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <asp:ListItem Selected="true">All</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

In code behind, you can do this in page_load event,

```
chktopics.Items[0].Checked = ture;
```

Comment: What if anyone tries to uncheck it? Is it possible? Because my objective is to make the first element remain checked and also it should remain readonly i.e it should remain unchanged.